# C C++ Linking Error

Tags: gcc, g++, lapack, atlas

I am writing a program in C++ which uses the CLAPACK ATLAS library. However, I cannot get the program to link successfully to the library. I have written a small C program to better demonstrate the problem. Interestingly enough, this small demonstration program links just fine if I compile it with GCC, but I get the same linker errors when I try to compile with G++. I was hoping someone could help me figure out exactly what G++ and GCC are doing differently, so as to get the original program to link (The original program is a C++ program and I can't just "use GCC")

Here is the small demonstration program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <clapack.h>

// a is a column-major array of all the values in the matrix to invert
// The matrix's height and width are the same because it is a square matrix.
void invertMatrix(float *a, unsigned int height)
{
    int info, ipiv[height];
    info = clapack_sgetrf(CblasColMajor, height, height, a, height, ipiv);
    info = clapack_sgetri(CblasColMajor, height, a, height, ipiv);
}

void displayMatrix(float *a, unsigned int height, unsigned int width)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                    printf("%1.3f ", a[height*j + i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void multiplyMatrix(float *a, unsigned int aheight, unsigned int awidth, float *b, unsigned int bwidth, float *c)
{
    cblas_sgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, aheight, bwidth, awidth, 1.0f, a, aheight, b, awidth, 0.0f, c, aheight);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    float a[9], b[9], c[9];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
            a[i] = 1.0f*rand()/RAND_MAX;
            b[i] = a[i];
    }
    displayMatrix(a, 3, 3);
    invertMatrix(a, 3);
    multiplyMatrix(a, 3, 3, b, 3, c);
    displayMatrix(c, 3, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile this with GCC, it works just fine:

```
$ gcc -o linearalgebra linearalgebra.c -I /usr/include/atlas -L /usr/lib64/atlas/ -llapack -lblas
$ ./linearalgebra
0.723 0.755 0.753
0.179 0.912 0.349
0.642 0.265 0.530

1.000 -0.000 0.000
0.000 1.000 0.000
0.000 0.000 1.000

$
```

And when I try to compile this with G++, it gives linker errors:

```
$ g++ -o linearalgebra linearalgebra.c -I /usr/include/atlas -L /usr/lib64/atlas/ -llapack -lblas
/tmp/ccuhmDKE.o: In function `multiplyMatrix(float*, unsigned int, unsigned int, float*, unsigned int, float*)':
linearalgebra.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm(CBLAS_ORDER, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, float, float const*, int, float const*, int, float, float*, int)'
/tmp/ccuhmDKE.o: In function `invertMatrix(float*, unsigned int)':
linearalgebra.c:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `clapack_sgetrf(CBLAS_ORDER, int, int, float*, int, int*)'
linearalgebra.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `clapack_sgetri(CBLAS_ORDER, int, float*, int, int const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Last but not least: Some information about my system:
Operating System: `Fedora 10 (Linux hostname 2.6.27.25-170.2.72.fc10.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jun 21 18:39:34 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)`
Libraries:

```
$ yum list | grep lapack
lapack.x86_64                        3.1.1-4.fc10                 installed
lapack-debuginfo.x86_64              3.1.1-4.fc10                 installed
lapack-devel.x86_64                  3.1.1-4.fc10                 @fedora
$ yum list | grep blas
blas.x86_64                          3.1.1-4.fc10                 installed
blas-devel.x86_64                    3.1.1-4.fc10                 installed
$ yum list | grep atlas
atlas.x86_64                         3.6.0-15.fc10                installed
atlas-debuginfo.x86_64               3.6.0-15.fc10                installed
atlas-devel.x86_64                   3.6.0-15.fc10                @fedora
```

Also, for bonus points: What exactly is the historical and functional relationship between LAPACK and ATLAS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to link a C++ program to a C library you have to make sure that all functions etc. in the C library is prefixed with `extern "C"`. The C++ compiler mangles C++ symbol names which makes it impossible for the linker to match then symbols with the names in the C library. You can use a block to declare your C symbols:

```
extern "C" {
  ...
}
```

You may be able to define a preprocessor symbol to instruct `cblas.h` and `clapack.h` to include the necessary `extern "C"` in front of all declarations.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I wrapped the lapack and blas header #include statements in a extern "C" {} block, and now it works with G++, because G++ knows not to mangle the names when it comes across the declaration.